# document.ready not fired - except with 'alerts' in it

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jcarousellite

I have implemented JCarouselLite in my ASP.net website and it works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari but not in Internet Explorer. It seems like document.ready doesn't get called. To test this I included some alerts in the call, and to my surprise JCarousel works every time - but only if I put the alerts in there.

So this works fine (this cannot of course not be used in production):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        alert("document.ready (start)")
       });

    $(".slider").jCarouselLite({
        vertical: true,
        auto: 1000,
        speed: 1000,
        visible: 6
    })
    {
        alert("document.ready (end)")
    };
</script>
```

But without the alerts it 'sometimes' works.

Can anyone please explain what is going on?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: have you added the jquery library before this code.

Comment: Shouldn't the `.jCarouselLite()` call be _inside_ the document ready handler?

Answer (score 0):

You have some JS errors:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    alert("document.ready (start)");
   $(".slider").jCarouselLite({
    vertical: true,
    auto: 1000,
    speed: 1000,
    visible: 6,
   });
    alert("document.ready (end)");
});
```

You have extra curly braces here:

```
{
  alert("document.ready (end)")
};
```